# Slow start when using Service object instead of firefox_profile

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I got a Deprecation Warning:

```
firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
```

So I changed the python script to use a service object. Now it takes takes half a minute to start firefox marionette. It starts instantly using the firefox_profile method.

I wonder why, and how to cure the problem?

```
Firefox 116.0.3 (64-bit)
Python3 Selenium 4.0.0~a1+dfsg1-1.1
Geckodriver for Firefox 0.33.0 (2023-04-03, a80e5fd61076)
geckodriver is executable and resides in /usr/local/bin/ which is in the PATH.
```

Also in /usr/local/bin/ is an executable link-file named firefox and it points to "/opt/firefox/firefox".
If this file is removed, firefox webdriver doesnt start, although the geckodriver is available.
Same thing if geckodriver is removed and the linkfile stays.

Here is the script I use for testing:

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# Options
options = Options()

## Option for using a custom Firefox profile
options.profile = '/home/rooper/dev/python/projects/firefox_profile/'

## Enable headless
#options.headless = True

# Specify custom geckodriver path
service = Service('/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')

browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=service)
while True:
    print(browser.title +"Hello")
    sleep(1)    

#browser.quit()
#sys.exit()
```